# Is it possible to make someone not be able to jump?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making a map and I want to know if it's possible to make someone not be able to jump, is there any command for this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: What is the name of your map?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by giving players a jump boost of level over 127 (which overflows, and becomes negative). For example:

```
/effect @a jump_boost <duration> 128 true
```

Comment: When I do that, if I put in any number for duration, it says it's not a valid number, what should I do about  it?

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect give ...`